# TURTLE - Change coordinates based on the length of a list, if statement, or while loop? turtle.goto()

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

This is the code for a calculator I made with Turtle, the list contains the different digits and operators to be used. The If statement checks the lenght of the list, and for every +1 element added to the list, it moves the coordinates of the turtle pen which will then write the numbers that were input by the user in a calculator "display".

How can a I make this code more efficient?

```
def order_display():
    if len(list) == 1:
        turtle.goto(245, 110)
    elif len(list) == 2:
        turtle.goto(230, 110)
    elif len(list) == 3:
        turtle.goto(215, 110)
    elif len(list) == 4:
        turtle.goto(200, 110)
    elif len(list) == 5:
        turtle.goto(185, 110)
    elif len(list) == 6:
        turtle.goto(170, 110)
    elif len(list) == 7:
        turtle.goto(155, 110)
    elif len(list) == 8:
        turtle.goto(140, 110)
    elif len(list) == 9:
        turtle.goto(125, 110)
    elif len(list) == 10:
        turtle.goto(110, 110)
    elif len(list) == 11:
        turtle.goto(95, 110)
    elif len(list) == 12:
        turtle.goto(80, 110)
    elif len(list) == 13:
        turtle.goto(65, 110)
    elif len(list) == 14:
        turtle.goto(50, 110)
    elif len(list) == 15:
        turtle.goto(35, 110)
    elif len(list) == 16:
        turtle.goto(20, 110)
    elif len(list) == 17:
        turtle.goto(5, 110)
    elif len(list) == 18:
        turtle.goto(-10, 110)
    else:
        print("DOES NOTHING")
```

Comment: Is it normal that there are x values gaps of 15, EXCEPT between `len(list) == 2` and `len(list) == 3` ?

Comment: just realized I messed up there, thanks!

Comment: Okay ^^ Can you edit your question so I can see what the coordinates must be ?

Comment: Done, len(list) == 2 X value is 230 and == 3 is 215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop :

```
if 1 <= len(list) <= 18:
    for i in range(1, 18):
        if len(list) == i:
            turtle.goto(-15 * i + 260, 110)
else: print("DOES NOTHING")
```